# How can I create an object using a Type

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I want to overwrite the method SaveChanges() from DbContext to add some controls in it. My idea is to find all objects that had been modify and reload their previous values to compare with the new ones.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries( EntityState.Modified);  // will store a list of all modified items

    foreach(var change in changes)
    {
      string tableName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;     
      Type myType = Type.GetType(change.Entity.GetType().FullName); 
      string itemID = change.CurrentValues.GetValue(0);

      string request = "select * from dbo."+tableName+" where ID="+ itemID;
      // the following line does not work
      var myObj = db.Database.SqlQuery(myType, request, new SqlParameter("p1", "") );

    }
}
```

myObj type is DbRawSqlQuery. I can not find how to create an object with the type 'myType' then query the database to find it.

Comment: Look at [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Before getting into your issue, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico: I want to able to log somewhere which values of my model have been changed by comparing my model with its previous value.

Comment: @sbat: I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this as solution:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries( EntityState.Modified);  // will store a list of all modified items

    foreach(var change in changes)
    {
      string tableName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;     
      Type myType = Type.GetType(change.Entity.GetType().FullName); 
      string itemID = change.CurrentValues.GetValue(0);

      string request = "select * from dbo."+tableName+" where ID="+ itemID;
      object myObj_4 = db.Database.SqlQuery(myType, request, new SqlParameter("p0", tempID)).Cast<object>().ToList().First();
      foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in myType.GetProperties().Where(g=>!g.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
      {
            var oldValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(myObj_4) ?? "";
            var newValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(changes.First().Entity) ?? "";

            if (oldValue.ToString() != newValue.ToString())
            {
                //Log the diferences between object
            }
      }
    }
}
```

At this point it's doing the job. I'm not sure it's the best way to do it or fast enough.